# GoLang Get Method Returns Missing Info

Tags: go, postman, marshalling, go-gorm, go-gin

I am trying to get some profile info using golang, gin and gorm frame works. Here is my data struct.

```
type Model struct {
Skills         []string
Languages      []string
}
```

And my method;

```
    var skillname []string
    var languagename []string
    var langs []Models.Language
    var skills []Models.Skill

session, _ := store.Get(c.Request, "sessioncontrol")
    i := session.Values["sessionid"]

skillcount := int(Config.DB.Find(&skills, "user_id = ?", i).RowsAffected)
langcount := int(Config.DB.Find(&langs, "user_id = ?", i).RowsAffected)

fmt.Println(langcount)
fmt.Println(skillcount)
    for _, lang := range langs {
        var langc Models.LanguageCatalog
        
        fmt.Printf("lang:")
        fmt.Println(langcount)
        Config.DB.First(&langc, "id = ?", lang.LanguageCatalogID)
        
        fmt.Printf("catalogname:")
        fmt.Println(langc.Name)
        
        languagename = append(languagename, langc.Name)
    }

    for _, skill := range skills {
        var skillc Models.SkillCatalog
        
        fmt.Printf("skill:")
        fmt.Println(skillcount)
        Config.DB.First(&skillc, "id = ?", skill.SkillCatalogID)
        
        fmt.Printf("catalognames:")
        fmt.Println(skillc.Name)
        
        skillname = append(skillname, skillc.Name)
    }

    for _, snm := range skillname {
        fmt.Println(snm)
    }
    for _, lnm := range languagename {
        fmt.Println(lnm)
    }
    model.Skills = skillname
    model.Languages = languagename

    for _, skname := range model.Skills {
        fmt.Println(skname)
    }
    for _, lname := range model.Languages {
        fmt.Println(lname)
    }

    err := c.ShouldBindJSON(&model)
    c.JSON(200, model)

    fmt.Print(err)
    return
```

I used fmt methods to check whether data is actually receiving or not. And it is. Here is my terminal output;

```
2
4
lang:2

catalogname:Spanish
lang:2

catalogname:German
skill:4

catalognames:Java
skill:4

catalognames:.net
skill:4

catalognames:JQuery
skill:4

catalognames:Go
Java
.net
JQuery
Go
Spanish
German
Java
.net
JQuery
Go
Spanish
German
json: cannot unmarshal object into Go struct field Model.Languages of type string
```

I really have 4 skills record and 2 language method like  printed in the terminal at the database. However when I call GET method using postman what I got is;

```
{
  "Languages": [
        "Spanish"
    ],
 "Skills": [
        "Java",
        ".net"
    ]
}
```

Since I got "cannot unmarshal" error, I tried same by using model arrays instead of string arrays but the result was same without the error message. What should I do in order to get full data by GET call. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess that the request you are passing in from postman includes a request body (e.g. `{"Skills":["Java",".net"],"Languages":["Spanish"]}`). That being the case we can duplicate the issue with:

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net/http/httptest"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

type Model struct {
    Skills    []string
    Languages []string
}

func main() {
    // Simulate an HTTP request (enables us to provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example)
    requestTxt := bytes.NewBuffer([]byte(`{"Skills":["Java",".net"],"Languages":["Spanish"]}`))
    req := httptest.NewRequest("GET", "/", requestTxt)
    w := httptest.NewRecorder()
    c, _ := gin.CreateTestContext(w)
    c.Request = req

    // Populate the slices (the database queries are irrelevant - you have shown that they work)
    skills := []string{"Java", ".net", "JQuery"}
    langs := []string{"Spanish", "German"}

    model := Model{
        Skills:    skills,
        Languages: langs,
    }

    // Code as per your question
    err := c.ShouldBindJSON(&model)
    fmt.Println("ShouldBindJSON Error", err)

    c.JSON(200, model)

    // Output the response that would be sent back to postman
    body, _ := io.ReadAll(w.Result().Body)
    fmt.Println("response: ", string(body))
}
```

Running this gives me the result you say you are getting:

```json
{"Skills":["Java",".net"],"Languages":["Spanish"]}
```

The reason that this is happening is that [`context.ShouldBindJSON`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.ShouldBindJSON) process the *request INTO* the variable you pass; it is used when you expect the request to contain JSON and want to unmarshal that into a Go `struct`. So you are putting data into `model` and then overwriting it with the call to `ShouldBindJSON`.

To fix this remove the line `err := c.ShouldBindJSON(&model)` (and the line printing the error) and the result will be as expected:

```json
{"Skills":["Java",".net","JQuery"],"Languages":["Spanish","German"]}
```

*Note*: As I said at the start this is based on some guesswork. If this does not help please modify the code I have provided so that it matches your situation (if you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) then it's a lot simpler to understand/answer your question).